# Scanner throws exception

Tags: java, inputstream, java.util.scanner

I have following code to read entire file data:

```
scan = new Scanner(zf.getInputStream(ze));
if(scan.hasNext())
    fullText = scan.useDelimiter("\\A").next();
```

where `zf` and `ze` are `ZipFileInputStream` and `ZipEntry`. Randomly on certain occasions I see below exception. Any idea?

> ```
> java.util.InputMismatchException
>   at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:840)
>   at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1347)
> ```

Comment: thats a standard java class i guess. not my own

Comment: You were previously asking about an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, then edited the question to ask about a different `InputMismatchException`, rendering the existing answers to your question useless.  If you have two separate problems, ask two separate questions, don't re-use the same question.

Comment: Could you share the contents of file which you're reading? And how often does it occur?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the source code for Scanner.java, line 883, and see what would cause an IndexOutOfBoundsException there.  Then trace that variable back and see why the index is out of bounds.  Java's source code is public, so just make sure that you have the Java source linked properly into your project.

Comment: i saw another exception before it so may be this gives some clue?